# How can i do the opposite of random.seed?

Tags: python

```
def encrypt(message, key):
    random.seed(key)
    l = range(len(message))
    random.shuffle(l)
    return "".join([message[x] for x in l])
```

This is the encryption method and my task is to find out how to decrypt it. I understand that `random.seed(key)` will arrange the randomize by the value of key.

How can I reverse it?

Comment: If it were easy/possible to do that, the encryption would be useless.  The whole point of (pseudo-)random number generators is you can't figure out their past or future state.

Comment: That's not really what `random.seed` does. It seeds your PRNG such that if you use the same seed, each sequential call to `random.random` is the same.

Comment: If you really want to 'decrypt' the message, generate all possible permutations of the encrypted message and try to find any of them that have a meaning.

Comment: I still don't understand. For example i know that x = 500 and i see random.seed(500) random.suffle(list) there isnt a way that i can reverse it?

Comment: @TomerBerezovsky you're not supposed to. mgilson came up with a tricky way to make it work, but it's a sign you're probably doing this the wrong way. Specifically because (as he mentions) this isn't actually encryption.

Answer (score 5):

First, this isn't exactly encryption.  It's shuffling.  If you do this, you should definitely not consider your message "safe".  I'm sure there are lots of very clever people out there who could figure out what your message said initially...

You're looking for a way to unshuffle something that was shuffled if you know the random seed.  This *is* possible within a single python process (if you know the key):

```
import random
def shuffle(message, key):
    random.seed(key)
    l = range(len(message))
    random.shuffle(l)
    return "".join([message[x] for x in l])

def unshuffle(shuffled_message, key):
    random.seed(key)
    l = range(len(shuffled_message))
    random.shuffle(l)
    out = [None] * len(shuffled_message)
    for i, x in enumerate(l):
        out[x] = shuffled_message[i]
    return ''.join(out)


hello_world = shuffle('Hello World', 0)
print hello_world
print unshuffle(hello_world, 0)
```

The idea is that `random.shuffle` will map from one index to another.  It does this pseudo-randomly which means that it will always behave the same way given the same seed.  So then, the trick is just figuring out how to invert that mapping.

Comment: Ooh that's smart. I was trying to dig for the source of `random.shuffle` to see if it does some reversible operation given a known state at start (like assigning a `random.random()` to every element and sorting by that or etc)

Comment: Clever.  I was looking at reversing the action shuffle did, but shuffling a sequence of the same length is much simpler!

Comment: Yeah, my _biggest_ question is whether you could actually take a message shuffled by one python process and unshuffle it using a different python process.  e.g. Is there any reason (like machine architecture) why different processes would shuffle differently given the same seed?

Comment: In theory the purpose of the seed is to be able to reproduce the same results, so you should be able to.  I don't know how strictly that's enforced by Python though.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily decrypt this you just have reverse the indexing (assuming you use the same key):

```
def decrypt(message, key):
    random.seed(key)
    l = list(range(len(message)))
    random.shuffle(l)
    return "".join(message[i] for i, x in sorted(enumerate(l), key=lambda x: x[1]))

>>> decrypt(encrypt('Hello World', 0), 0)
'Hello World'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def decrypt(shuffled_msg, key):
    random.seed(key)
    l = range(len(shuffled_msg))
    random.shuffle(l)
    d = sorted(zip(l, shuffled_msg))
    return ''.join([b for (a, b) in d])

>>> key = 14
>>> shuffled = encrypt('somestring', key=key)
>>> shuffled
'essmigntro'
>>> decrypt(shuffled, key=key)
'somestring'
```